# Passing multiple variables not files to jq command

Tags: json, shell, jq

I have two variables in shell script, each one contains a JSON data.

I wanted to merge these using command

```
jq '.' $var1 $var2
```

where `echo $var1 => {"key1": "value1"}`

```
echo $var2 => {"key2": "value2"}
```

but it does not work, however when i write contents of these variables into file1 and file2 respectively, It works fine `jq '.' file1.json file2.json`
it works perfectly.
Any help regarding how to pass multiple variables to jq command will be appreciated.

Comment: post your `$var1 $var2` contents

Comment: Why don't you simply use `echo "$var1$var2"` if you want to _merge_ both variables?

Comment: `jq --argjson var1 "$var1" --argjson var2 "$var2" -n '$var1 + $var2'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "merge" you mean something like jq's `add`, then you could simply write:

```
jq -n "$var1 + $var2"
```

More generally, if your jq supports the --argson command-line option, then you could use it; otherwise, you could use —arg but some care would then be needed to do any required conversions. In either case, you will probably also want to use the -n command-line option.

If you are using a shell such as bash, another set of options is based on process substitution, e.g.

```
jq -s add <(echo "$var1") <(echo "$var2")
```

If your `echo` is unsuitable, you could use some other alternative (e.g. printf).

If process substitution is overkill, then another option, as @chepner pointed out, is simply to use "$var1 $var2", e.g.

```
jq -s add "$var1 $var2"
```

Finally, if the shell variables have been exported (i.e., if they are available as "environment" variables), then you can use jq's `env` function: `env.var1 + env.var2`

Comment: Thank You, I almost tried this way except a right syntax earlier.

Comment: `jq -s add <<< "$var1$var"` would be simpler and avoid any potential issues  with `echo` processing backslashed characters.

Comment: $var1$var2 will give unexpected results in cases such as `var1=true; var2=false`, but adding a space should be fine.